# How can I integrate jscs autofix feature into vim?

Tags: javascript, vim, jscs

I'm trying to get a command I can run within vim to get [jscs auto correct](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/issues/516) formatting issues in my code. So far I've come up with :

`:nmap <F5> :!jscs -x .<CR>`

which is ok, but it runs it on the entire directory and I need to confirm to vim that I want to reload the buffer. Is there a way to get vim to fix the current file only and didsplay the changes without reloading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will pipe the current file through jscs's fix mode whenever you save the file (your mileage may vary using this in practice!):

```
function! JscsFix()
    "Save current cursor position"
    let l:winview = winsaveview()
    "Pipe the current buffer (%) through the jscs -x command"
    % ! jscs -x
    "Restore cursor position - this is needed as piping the file"
    "through jscs jumps the cursor to the top"
    call winrestview(l:winview)
endfunction
command! JscsFix :call JscsFix()

"Run the JscsFix command just before the buffer is written for *.js files"
autocmd BufWritePre *.js JscsFix
```

It also creates a command `JscsFix` which you can run whenever you want with `:JscsFix`.
To bind it to a key (in this case `<leader>g`) use `noremap <leader>g :JscsFix<cr>`.

Comment: When I add those lines to my vimrc, it's ok the first time, and I can use jscs by pressing F3 to restyle my file. But the next time I want to source my vimrc again (using :so %) I get these errors: Error detected while processing /home/omid/.vimrc:
line  197:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Here's my full snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/2pLoczws/

Comment: Changing the line `command JscsFix :call JscsFix()` to add the exclamation mark after command, e.g. `command! JscsFix :call JscsFix()` might do what you want?

Answer (score 5):

[vim-autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) supports JSCS out of the box. Invoke its `:Autoformat` command to fix only the current file. Note it edits the file in the current buffer, so the changes will just appear; you will not be prompted to reload.

Comment: Great tip! Additionally run auto-format on save with `autocmd BufWritePre *.js Autoformat`.